# How would Hindu theologians respond to this quote by Plato?

Tags: philosophy, atma, maya, jiva, shad-darshana

> "The evil is that the soul of every man, when it is greatly pleased or
> pained by anything, is compelled to believe that the object which
> caused the emotion is very distinct and very true; but it is not.
> These objects are mostly the visible ones, are they not?” “Certainly.”
>
> “And when this occurs, is not the soul most completely put in bondage
> by the body?”
>
> “How so?”
>
> “Because each pleasure or pain nails it as with a nail to the body and
> rivets it on and makes it corporeal, so that it fancies the things are
> true which the body says are true."
>
> Plato, *Phaedo*

How would Hindu theologians respond to this quote? Would they agree or disagree?

Comment: What does Plato mean by soul? Does he mean a human or the Atman? If he means a human then what he says will agree with Vedanta. If he means the Atman then there will be disagreement. A clear understanding of soul is needed to answer this question.

Comment: I am not be a scholar but the following observations were made. 1) Plato says that a person mistakes the non-real to be real after interacting with it. However Vedanta says that it is due to the influence of avidya which causes a person to mistake the non-real to be real 2) Plato states that emotion drags the soul into a corporeal form, but our doctrine states that the fruits of karma driven by intellect are solely responsible for the soul's corporeal form.